# Search in 1 column with where and statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search in a column with a where statement. So my database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (
 zID varchar(20), 
 tID varchar(30)
 );

INSERT INTO test
(zID, tID)
VALUES
('1','1'),
('1','2'),
('2','1'),
('2','2'),
('3','1');
```

And Then I use the following SQL statement to search:

```
SELECT * from test where tID = 1 and tID = 2
```

So when I put this the query should return `1` and `2` but not `3` all of which are `zIDs`, I have tried using an `in` but this would return all the `zIDs`. This is not what I want though, so my question is how can I search with the and?

Instead using `in` which is kind of like an `or` instead.

Heres a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1bd5/2)

Comment: Why aren't you just searching by `zID` then?

Comment: @Yuck Well this would one table of a few I will be searching in, but this is the first step in me trying to get the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with this is to use a `COUNT()` aggregate which verifies that the total number of `DISTINCT tID` per `zID` group is equal to 2 when filtered via an `IN()` clause.

```
SELECT zID
FROM test
/* Limit rows to tID 1,2
WHERE tID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY zID
/* Verify that the total DISTINCT number of tID
   per group of zID is 2, that way you know *both*
   values are present.
   Substitute the total number of values in the IN() for the comparison
   against COUNT() (substitute for 2 here) to do this dynamically
*/
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tID) = 2
```

[The updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1bd5/5)

The above only returns the `zID`, but it can be expanded to return all columns using a `JOIN` or another `IN()`  clause.

```
/* Get all columns for the zID returned inside */
SELECT * FROM test WHERE zID IN (
  SELECT zID
  FROM test
  WHERE tID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY zID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tID) = 2
)
```

Or with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT test.*
FROM
  test
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT zID
      FROM test
      WHERE tID IN (1,2)
      GROUP BY zID
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tID) = 2
    ) tz ON test.zID = tz.zID
```

Comment: Ah right well can I ask, would this still would in a similar manner if it was dynamic? So say I don't know the number of items in the array would everything be in the same layout if I can ask. Edit: I think I understand, the count is the count of the array I assume?

Comment: @user3144542 Yes, the `COUNT()` value is compared against the number of values in the `IN()` clause, originating from your array. As long as you know how long your array is (you should be able to know that), substitute that value for the `2` in `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tID) = 2`